# MAMP Lion - Slow Result from Database to Client

Tags: php, mysql, macos, osx-lion, mamp

I am dealing with a production box (mac Lion) running much slower than a production Snow Leopard.  Here however is an oddity that I stumbled upon quite accidentally while working on the Lion issue.

If I have a looping message coming from a php script that I'm logging to a file, all the other php scripts being executed during that time with database calls return results much faster to the client.   If I turn off that script - the other scripts slow down in returning results.

What is the reasoning for this?  I'm hoping this will lead me to the adjustment needed to fix this slow response.